# Prevent page panning on Windows Phone 7 browser

Tags: css, windows-phone-7, canvas

I'm trying to figure out if there is a css property (or any other method really) that can be used in windows phone 7's browser to keep it from panning the page if you touch inside of a certain element.

Specifically I have a Canvas element that will be used to sign a driver application for employment and at the moment Windows Phone 7 is the only mobile device that it doesn't function on.

So the gist of it is that there is a canvas element to sign in and it function on android and iphone, but on the wp7 device it just moves the page around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few suggestions and research online it appears that at the moment there is not a way to do what I'm wanting.  It looks like Microsoft hasn't built in all the touch elements that are used in iPhone/Android.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
/// <summary>
        ///   Wraps a Html segment with html and body tags, and sets the viewport to prevent zooming.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name = "html">The html segment to wrap</param>
        /// <returns>A wrapped string with html and body tags</returns>
        public static string WrapHtmlAndDisableZooming(string html)
        {
            return html == null
                       ? null
                       : string.Format(html,
                                       "<html><head><meta name='viewport' content='width=320,user-scalable=no'/></head><body>{0}</body></html>",
                                       html);
        }
```

Comment: Will this function if the element is inside of a form?  Sorry I've never attempted anything like what you have mentioned.  Also I don't need/want to prevent zooming, I need the screen to not move when they are touching with their finger inside of the canvas element.

Comment: @Jared I don't know, you can try. I've only used it for displaying a EULA